# Mthaml composer package with Laravel 4 - Howto?

Tags: php, haml, laravel, laravel-4

**Original:** Has anyone figured out, or is there anyone interested in helping me figure out how to use haml with Laravel 4?

**Update:** A fresh implementation of Laravel 4 using HAML([MtHaml](https://packagist.org/packages/mthaml/mthaml)) is being tested.
You can get it at [my Github repo](https://github.com/villimagg/Laravel-MtHaml) and test it out.

**Note:**
Mind that at this stage only the HAML/PHP engine is working, thus template inheritance is not yet working. For template inheritance to work MtHaml needs to be run through the HAML/Twig engine which then will give us all of Twigs Template Engines power and a really nice OOP-like syntax for our loops and such.

If anyone likes to help out with finishing the package to include Twig for a fully functional Template Engine feel free to Fork and Pull!! :D

Thank you.

Comment: Hope I'm not the only person in the world thinking about this?

Comment: I'm looking for that too :(

Comment: @TomSarduy You can test out a fresh implementation of Laravel 4 with MtHaml/PHP at: https://github.com/villimagg/Laravel-MtHaml .

Comment: @TomSarduy Keep in mind that this is using the HAML/PHP engine, thus template inheritance is not yet available. For template inheritance to work we need the HAML/Twig engine to work. We are still testing that out.

Comment: Ok, keep the good work! I'm looking forward to test it!

Answer (score 2):

Does it need to be any more complicated than using the Composer package?

https://github.com/arnaud-lb/MtHaml

Answer (score 1):

I just created this because I wanted to get into HAML on a project.  Let me know if it works for your needs: https://github.com/BKWLD/laravel-haml

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get Laravel 4 working with dzony's implementation of Jade ( https://github.com/dz0ny/jade.php ) let me know if you are interested.

It does work with template inheritance using Blade Engine.

Comment: Can you post your implementation?

Comment: I'm really interested to hear more of this, too!